# Alternative to flushing cache in dashboard when making theme changes?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.4

Every time I make changes to the theme I'm developing I have to go into the dashboard and clear static files, css/js cache and afterwards the magento cache (in that order). I'm running in `developer` mode.

Is there any way to avoid having to do this every time I make a change? Or, is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Run `bin/magento cache:clean` or `bin/magento cache:flush` in your terminal after each change
2. Install https://github.com/mage2tv/magento-cache-clean, it makes a world of difference

Comment: Number 2 is fantastic!